# How do I get the clicked button name with getElemetByName?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get value of button which is clicked, or determine which button was clicked.

From code below, I'm getting all values but I just want the button that was clicked.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckedFruits () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName ("fruit");
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].click) {
                alert ("The " + (i+1) + ". button is click");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<input id="Text1" name="fruit" type="button" value="apple" onclick="GetCheckedFruits ()" /><br />

<input id="Text1" name="fruit" type="button" value="banana" onclick="GetCheckedFruits ()" /><br />

<input id="Text1" name="fruit" type="button" value="blackberry" onclick="GetCheckedFruits ()" /><br />
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Which button is click? Do you mean CLICKED or CLICKABLE? Or Checked? Are these checkboxes? Post the whole html please. Might be easier to figure out what you want.

Comment: at the same time how can it be possible to click so many buttons that you are going to find the clicked button... also you can't find the button which is clicked... on buttons, OnClick, OnDoubleClick, onMouseOver are events.... so if they are clicked we are going to perform some action...

Comment: `elements[i].click` will click the button and will not find whether it is clicked or not... hence OP is getting all button clicked....

Comment: is it something like this?? U have three submit button as Add, Delete, View and you want to find which button is clicked?? I will give you solution shortly...

Comment: Look at the function name. I'm sure he has many checkboxes like Apple, Orange, Grapes, Pear, etc. And he might want a list of selected fruits.

Comment: All but the JS was hidden in this post due to a lack of formatting, which is probably why you saw down votes. I've edited for that, as well as spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to alert the message when the button is clicked, you would have to use an event like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckedFruits () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName ("fruit");
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i].onclick = function() {
                // You can put anything you want here
                // the variable `this` is the clicked button
                alert ("The " + this.value + " button is click");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

EDIT:

In the case you are working with checkboxes and are trying to get which fruits where selected, this will work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetCheckedFruits () {
        var elements = document.getElementsByName ("fruit");
        for (var i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            if (elements[i].checked == 1) {
                alert ("The " + elements[i].value + " button is click");
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't know why the downvote. But looking at the function name, it seems the OP is talking about checkboxes.

Comment: @Nirmal You are probably right. I did not consider the function name. The question is not quite clear though.

Comment: Upvoted you to zero. You can't lose when the question was not clear.

Comment: @Nirmal Thank you! It's interesting. I suggested exactly the same as Ravindra Gullapalli just a bit earlier and with a cleaner separation of markup and code. Still I am getting the downvotes. :)

Answer (score 1):

change

```
if (elements[i].click) {
     alert ("The " + (i+1) + ". button is click");
}
```

to

```
if (elements[i].type == 'button') {
    alert ("The " + elements[i].value + " button is click");
}
```

thats it.

**EDIT**

Try this

function GetCheckedFruits (clickedButton) {
                alert ("The " + clickedButton.value + ". button is click");
        }
    }

and add the buttons like this

`<input type="button" value="Button1" onclick="{GetCheckedFruits(this);}" />`
`<input type="button" value="Button2" onclick="{GetCheckedFruits(this);}" />`
`<input type="button" value="Button3" onclick="{GetCheckedFruits(this);}" />`

Comment: thank, but i still getting alerts for all butons not just for button click

Comment: you want all buttons which are clicked?

Comment: how i get just for button which is click, i have 3 buttons

Comment: that makes no sense. get someone who speaks english and rephrase the question please.